# How to use Google Play Authutil with Unity

Tags: android, authentication, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I'm developing game with Unity and we are using Game Center on iOS and GPGS on Android to authenticate player. On iOS side we are verifying the authenticity of the Game Center id from Apple with our own 3rd party server. I'm trying to do this with Android as well but i'm getting stumped on how I can get the players account email for the googleAuthUtil.
[GoogleAuthUtil](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html)

At the moment we are using Unity's own Social Api with Google Play Games plugin for Unity. This will login the player to the GPGS give me access the players Google Play player information but it wont give me the account email needed for the AuthUtil. Is there a way to extract account email from GPGS account that is already logged in, which i could use to generate the authentication token with AuthUtil. I have a "extension plugin" that talks to the Unity from native code and other way around but I can't figure out how i could extract the account email.

In summary how can i get GPGS account email from player that is already logged in, in my game?

Answer (score -1):

A [recent update to the Google Play Games Unity plugin enabled support](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/commit/bc62f4987188d43a796b1d3a58dab9b9b5bb9bfc) for retrieving auth tokens for users.

If you have configured your project for access, you should now be able to call:

```
PlayGamesPlatform.getUserEmail();
```